# kafka kraft sasl jaas config setup using docker bitnami and offset explorer

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, bitnami-kafka

I am trying to setup a basic kafka running inside docker using bitnami kafka image with a jaas config and after trying all the combinations, I could not move forward.

Here is the docker-compose file

```
services:
  kafka:
    restart: always
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3.5.1
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/kafka/data:/bitnami/kafka
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9093:9093
      - 9094:9094
      - 9095:9095
    container_name: broker1
    environment:
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker1:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9094,SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9095
      KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@broker1:9093'
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT, SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093,EXTERNAL://:9094, SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9095
      KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
      KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID: X57tL522R6-loSmbUAbinA
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_NAME_SASL_PLAINTEXT_PLAIN_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: |
        org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
        username="admin" \
        password="admin-secret" \
        user_admin="admin-secret" \
        user_kafkabroker1="kafkabroker1-secret";
```

If I use port `9094` which is PLAINTEXT, I am able to connect to the kafka

If I use  `SASL_PLAINTEXT` port 9095, I am not able to connect via offset explorer and seeing the below error logs

```
broker1  | [2023-10-11 07:25:57,615] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=BROKER, nodeId=1] Failed authentication with /172.18.0.1 (channelId=172.18.0.2:9095-172.18.0.1:55502-91) (Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

offset explorer config
[image]

I followed almost all the available options from here : https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/kafka/README.md

Comment: Are you sure `KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_NAME_SASL_PLAINTEXT_PLAIN_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG` is the correct config? You can mount a JAAS config file as a volume, not use environment variables

Comment: Trying to avoid the jaas config file setup as the recommended way is to use the environment vars @OneCricketeer

Comment: I don't think it is, though. All Java services support JAAS files on disk. I don't actually see that config mentioned in the bitnami readme linked, either

Comment: After adding the below KAFKA_CFG_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: |
        org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required \
        username="admin" \
        password="admin-secret";

I could see the below log when starting the docker container
broker1  |  sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]

Updated the same in the question with image.

If I do not add the mentioned config, the log is 

broker1  |  sasl.jaas.config = null

@OneCricketeer

Comment: @One Here is the link : https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/kafka, search for `Refactor JAAS settings to use the recommended approach`

Comment: @OneCricketeer Even apache kafka document says https://kafka.apache.org/35/documentation.html#security_jaas_client

Read the first Point i.e. `JAAS configuration using client configuration property`

Comment: "**may** configure JAAS using the client configuration property"... Just because it's the first option doesn't mean it's "recommended"... Besides this, the bitnami image has custom logic around parsing it's environment variables. So yes, you'll need to explicitly add that key/value to set that broker config. I've never seen JAAS settings specific to a listener